# Why does Bloch state that it is impossible to subclass collections implementations?

Tags: java, collections, immutability

In "Effective Java" book Joshua Bloch says: "It is impossible to subclass any of the convenience implementation classes in the Collection Framework".

Why does he point it if ArrayList, LinkedList, HashSet etc. have public constructors and can be easily subclassed?

Could you please also explain me why can't we extend a mutable class by an immutable one?

If an immutable class has package-private constructor and fields and can be modified by a mutable child class anyway the INSTANCE of immutable will be created only for child class and a user will not use the parent class.

Comment: He doesn't talk about `LinkedList`. He talks about `java.util.Collections$SingletonSet` and `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`.

Comment: He probably meant to say *"It is impossible to subclass any of the convenience implementation classes in the Collection Framework **when using factory methods**"*

Comment: I also do not understand what you mean by "we cannot extend a mutable class by an immutable one". What does that mean to you? Extending mutable class and overriding all mutation methods to throw exceptions is definitely possible.

Comment: I am asking about extending an immutable class by a mutable as I thought at first that we couldn't extend collections just because they are immutable.

Answer (score 7):

Read the broader quote:

> **The main disadvantage of providing only static factory methods is that
>   classes without public or protected constructors cannot be subclassed**. The
>   same is true for nonpublic classes returned by public static factories. For example,
>   it is impossible to subclass any of the convenience implementation classes in the
>   Collections Framework.

It's talking about things like `Collections.unmodifiableList`, `Collections.singleton`, `Collections.synchronizedMap`: you can't subclass the type returned by those methods.

Comment: Sorry. I can subclass the type returned by Collections.unmodifiableList. It is List

Comment: @Pavel that's not what subclassing means.